# pkg-config doesn't find package file when folder is listed in PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: linux, package-management, gentoo

So here is my PKG_CONFIG_PATH contents:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

and here is the output of `locate lv2.pc` (lv2 is the library I'm trying to link with)

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/lv2.pc
```

yet here is the output of `pkg-config --modversion lv2`

```
Package lv2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lv2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'lv2' found
```

Any advice? I'm running gentoo fyi. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PkgConfig can only understand one location of a folder in the variable, not like PATH's syntax. You need to set it to the one where the location of *all* of your .pc files are, sadly.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: This may have changed since 2013, but the current pkg-config manpage says that `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is a colon-delimited (UNIX) / semicolon-delimited (Windows) *list* of paths to search. So if you had, say, Qt pkgconfig dir in ~/dev/qt/5.6/lib/pkgconfig and grpc pkgconfig in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, you could `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/dev/qt/5.6/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The manual says differently, you can specify multiple paths for PKG_CONFIG_PATH

From man-pkgconfig

PKG_CONFIG_PATH
              A  colon-separated  (on  Windows, semicolon-separated) list of directories to search for .pc files.  The default
              directory will always be searched after searching the path;

No so for PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR however.

PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
              Replaces the default pkg-config search directory.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/lib` is a red herring, why is the file in there and not in `/usr/lib`?

`emerge media-libs/lv2`

Comment: I figured it out a while ago actually, sorry for not updating my progress. I found out that the variable doesn't understand PATH syntax, it can only take in the location of one folder. But anyway, for this program (non) it uses bleeding-edge version of lv2, so I had to install latest from svn. Before it did work (when emerged, not compiled from source), probably because it was in /usr/lib rather than /usr/local/lib. Why did this become a red herring?

Comment: Because it is non Portage, there's =media-libs/lv2-9999 in the pro-audio overlay.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when PKG_CONFIG_PATH is correct but only sudo can find a package. It happens because `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` has incorrect permissions. For these cases a fix would be:

```
chmod 645 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```